# How can I message an Instagram user from Facebook Messenger now that my Instagram & Facebook accounts have been linked in the Meta Accounts Centre?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, instagram

I have successfully linked my Facebook and Instagram accounts in the Meta Accounts Center in both apps. My stories get automatically cross posted, so I know I works. But I’m not able to see any of my Instagram threads or contacts in messenger which is especially annoying now that the threads app has been decommissioned.